# Performant way to group elements in a collection into new collections with Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a collection (a Java List) of tens of thousands of elements and I'm writing a Clojure function that needs to split this list into several parts based on predicates.  In the end I have several Clojure collections with only elements matching the predicate associated with the collection.

The following code solves my problem but iterates over the input list 3 times.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
(defn divide-into-groups [col]
  (let [one (filter #(< % 3) col)
        two (filter #(and (>= % 3) (< % 6)) col)
        three (filter #(>= % 6) col)]
   [one two three]))
(divide-into-groups (shuffle (range 10)))
;[(2 0 1) (4 3 5) (6 8 7 9)]
```

I'm really looking for a functional Clojure solution.  I already know I could create three collections as vars and mutate them inside the `divide-into-groups` function and maybe that is the Clojure way.  If so, then please say so.

(NOTE: the predicates I use above are not the ones in my production code.  The data I'm working with is also not numbers.  This is just a SSCCE.  The answer to this question must be applicable to the general problem with arbitrary data in the collection and arbitrary predicates. And of course, performant.  To be clear, the lazy lists returned by `filter` will all be completely iterated over and used to generate some output.  So I cannot rely on lazy solutions ;-)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that *exactly* one of the functions is always true?

Comment: Yes, exactly one of the functions is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `group-by` is for. The only thing you need other than your predicates is to give each of your predicate groups a "name" to dictate what group it will be in:

```
(defn divide-into-groups [xs]
  (let [group (fn [x] (cond (>= x 6) :large
                            (>= 6 x 3) :medium
                            :else :small))]
    (group-by group xs)))

user> (divide-into-groups (shuffle (range 10)))
{:small [1 2 0], :large [6 9 8 7], :medium [3 4 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `partition-by`[1].

```
(partition-by (fn [x] (cond (< x 3) :coll-1 
                      (and (>= x 3) (< x 6)) :coll-2 
                      (>= x 6) :coll-3)) 
              (range 10))
```

The required function can be constructed programmatically from the sequence of predicate functions. The unique value, ie `:coll-1`, `:coll-2` etc can be anything, even the index of the predicate in the sequence.

EDIT:

```
;; updated to use map-indexed and some-fn as suggested by @Andre

(defn partitions
  [preds coll]
  (let [party-fn (apply some-fn 
                        (map-indexed (fn [idx pred] 
                                       #(when (pred %1) idx))
                                     preds))]
    (partition-by party-fn coll)))   

;; output
(partitions [ #(< %1 3) #(<= 3 %1 5) #(>= %1 6)] (range 10))
((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8 9))
```

[1] - https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by

Comment: Could be done more succiently with `map-indexed` + `some-fn`. But I think this is a good solution.

Comment: @Andre, Took a li'l while to grok what `some-fn` did :). Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you guys taking time to write out these answers.  Unfortunately, they do not solve the problem because the collection is not sorted and the predicates may not have anything to do with a sort order.  Try your solutions with `(shuffle (range 10))` and see if they produce the correct results.  If so then I can up vote this, otherwise it isn't a correct solution.